# Ubuntu screen flickering while booting up before the login screen

Tags: boot

I have installed ubuntu 19.10 in dual boot with windows 10.
When ever I boot ubuntu after selecting ubuntu from the grub menu I see a list of process running and ubuntu  logo flickering continuously.
The same thing also happend when I inserted the live usb for installing ubuntu.
I just can't understand what is the problem and searched for the solution everywhere but still facing the same issue.
If I am unable to explain the problem clearly then I have recorded video of what is happening and  [this is the link to the video is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfsOH48gfdc)
please watch for clear understading
and please help
[Screen continuously flickeing between these two screen***strong text***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVCeQ.png)

[errors that I am getting in system log but haven't seen anything like that while booting up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJug2.png)

Comment: Are you able to get to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu? Can you get to the # root prompt from there?

Comment: yes I can.... what to do next

Comment: First show me `sudo blkid` then `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -al /boot`. Also, does Windows boot properly?

Comment: Tell me your make/model computer, and the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: No, I switched to ubuntu after struggling wih ubuntu for a month.

Comment: I also talked to the customer care executive of my laptop company and he said that he looked into some file and found out that my system was not designed for Ubuntu that is why it is creating problems, from that day onwards I switched to windows. I would love to use ubuntu once I get other system.